# PHP response blank back to ajax for button press

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get some php code working for when a button is pressed as I need to make some updates to an SQL table later on.

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
  <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mr-1" name="Save" value="Save" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mr-1" name="Update" value="Update" />

    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'translation.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};

        $.ajax({
          url: 'translation.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: "text",
          success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
          }
          });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        switch ($_POST['action']) {
            case 'save':
                saveTrans();
                break;
            case 'update':
                updateTrans();
                break;
        }
    }

    function saveTrans() {

          echo "The save function is called.";
        exit;
    }

    function updateTrans() {
        echo "The update function is called.";
        exit;
    }
?>
```

The alert response in the js is giving me a blank alert somehow. Any idea why?

Comment: You actually didn't passed the data to the php script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'translation.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data:{action:clickBtnValue},
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
      }
      });
 });
```

Modify the type of the buttons to type="button" instead of type="submit".

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'translation.php?action=ok',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: "text",
          success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
          }
```

**php:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        switch ($_GET['action']) {
            case 'save':
                saveTrans();
                break;
            case 'update':
                updateTrans();
                break;
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mr-1" name="Save" value="Save" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mr-1" name="Update" value="Update" />

    </div>
```